# (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: spring, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I am getting ssl handshake exception after "Produced client Finished handshake message" Step in my java spring boot application (openjdk version "11.0.12").

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://server/api/": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
```

Can someone help? I referred multiple articles in stackoverflow and tried all the steps. I am not sure if I missed any step?

I am writing a java spring boot application to test 2 way SSL connection. I have done the below steps

1. Followed the below article and then created the application using RestTemplate in the same way like https://www.aurigait.com/blog/how-to-implement-2-way-ssl-using-spring-boot/ (I didnt create self signed certificate instead, I use the one which was created for our project)
2. I have the JKS file of my client application. Added the server public certificate as trust source to the client JKS file. I added the root CA also as trust source.
3. Provided the below settings in the IntelliJ Run -> Edit Configurations -> VM Options

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1 (Tried without this line also)
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\certificate\keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\certificate\keystore.jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=pass
```

4. server added the client public certificate as well as trust source.

error:

```
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.190 UTC|Finished.java:398|Produced client Finished handshake message (
"Finished": {
  "verify data": {
    0000: AA 4E 76 43 21 C8 E4 D5   4A 5F B6 4F 
  }'}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.190 UTC|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:241|WRITE: TLS12 handshake, length = 24
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.206 UTC|SSLCipher.java:1743|Plaintext before ENCRYPTION (
  0000: 14 00 00 0C AA 4E 68 43   84 C8 E4 D5 4A 5F B6 4F  .....NhC....J_.O
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.206 UTC|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:255|Raw write (
  0000: 16 03 03 00 34 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 DE 91 8F  ....(...........
  0010: 18 3B DC D0 84 2C 39 35   B0 3C C3 7E 9E 1C BF 27  .;...,95.<.....'
  0020: 10 23 E3 D0 D0 32 B8 D1   D2 5C C4 DA CC           .#.......\...
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.206 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:488|Raw read (
  0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.206 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.206 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:488|Raw read (
  0000: 02 28                                              .(
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.206 UTC|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:247|READ: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.206 UTC|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 10:30:01.206 UTC|TransportContext.java:341|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure (
"throwable" : {
.
.
.
javax.net.ssl|ALL|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 09:42:15.234 UTC|SSLSessionImpl.java:784|Invalidated session:  Session(1661506935062|SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 09:42:15.234 UTC|SSLSessionImpl.java:784|Invalidated session:  Session(1661506935124|TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 09:42:15.234 UTC|SSLSocketImpl.java:1656|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|16|scheduling-1|2022-08-26 09:42:15.234 UTC|SSLSocketImpl.java:1675|close the SSL connection (initiative)
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://server/api/": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
```

Comment: This server generated alert is pretty generic and can happen in various situations, like the client not sending a client certificate when expected or when the client certificate can not be verified by the server. Too much unknown here what the server expected and what the client provided. Check also server side logs for information about the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hi @SteffenUllrich, Thanks for the inputs. I will check with the server team as welll.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause for this issue is the certificate (JKS) which I passed didn't have the certificate chain (Issuer details). So the SSL handshake failed after the "Produced client Finished handshake message". I took another JKS which has the entire chain and I added the server certificate as trust source. SSL handshake and the HTTPS call is working as expected.